# swift project with cocoapods obj-c dependence

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods, match

I'm making a simple swift application which links an obj-c cocoapod dependency SFRoundProgressCounterView. My Podfile contains `use_frameworks!`. After installing pods and building the project I get 2 errors:

> SFCounterLabel.h:12:9: 'TTTAttributedLabel.h' file not found
>
> Could not build Objective-C module 'SFRoundProgressCounterView'

I checked that SFCounterLabel.h which is part of SFRoundProgressCounterView import TTTAttributedLabel:

```
#import "TTTAttributedLabel.h"
```

I tried to use MyProjectName-Bridging-Header.h with 
    #import "TTTAttributedLabel.h"
but without reason.

My version of Cocoapods is 0.39.0.

What should I do to link SFRoundProgressCounterView correctly to my swift project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like in [SFCounterLabel.h](https://github.com/simpliflow/SFRoundProgressCounterView/blob/97e6355efacbbfb374e013a812c430858ca5d6ef/SFRoundProgressCounterView/SFCounterLabel.h) SFRoundProgressCounterView needs to use the import syntax that supports frameworks. `#import <TTTAttributedLabel/TTTattributedLabel.h>` or `@import TTTAttributedLabel.TTTAttributedLabel;`